# How to validate birth year?

Tags: javascript, validation, function

For this homework I have to write a javascript code to validate the birth year is greater than 1870 and less than the current year plus one how can I combine them to show the same error message?

```
function isYearofBirthValid(birth) {
  "use strict";
  var alert = "";
  if(birth.length < 1870 && birth.length > 2013) {    <---- this part?
     alert("invalid year");
     return false;
  }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: what type is the parameter birth?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you want to avoid hard coding the max year, you could use `new Date().getFullYear() + 1` instead of `2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if statement instead:

```
function isYearofBirthValid(birth) {
    if(birth < 1870 || birth > 2013){
        alert("invalid year");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or if you actually want to look up what the next year is

```
function isYearofBirthValid(birth) {
    if(birth < 1870 || birth > new Date().getFullYear()+1){
        alert("invalid year");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then you call the function like so

```
var valid = isYearofBirthValid(1978); //valid = true
```

Comment: `&& birth > new Date().getFullYear()+1` ?

Comment: A value can never be less than 1870 and greater than 2013 at the same time, so the condition will always be false.

Comment: @ianpgall: Actually that was edited half a minute after I posted the comment. That it slightly more than I can see into the future. ;)

Comment: @ianpgall: Time of rollback 15:29:17. Did you really see that edit before it was rolled back?

Comment: @Guffa I guess so! Haha this isn't important anyways. This should've been commented on the OP anyways because they have the code that is `< 1870 && > 2013` (even though it was copied to this answer)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the or operator (`||`) instead of the and operator (`&&`). The birth date can never be less than 1870 and greater than 2013 at the same time.

Also, I don't think that you want to check the length of value, but the value itself.

```
if (birth < 1870 || birth > 2013)
```